# woocommerce get current product name in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, shortcode

I create a button in a current product page after `woocommerce_single_product_summary`

I would get information about the current product ( for example name and price) and through the button send an email to get information

this is the code of my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','content_after_addtocart_button' );

function content_after_addtocart_button() { 
echo '<div class="content-section">
<a href="mailto:riccardoairone@gmail.com?&subject= Richiesta Informazioni&body= product name ??? product price ??? ">
<input type="button" value="Richiedi Informazioni"/ ></a></div>'; 
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch product details from the global `$product` variable which WooCommerce set for each product. You can check following example to create URL.

```
function content_after_addtocart_button() {
    global $product;
    echo '<div class="content-section">';
    $url = 'mailto:riccardoairone@gmail.com?subject= Richiesta Informazioni';
    $url .= '&body=Product:' . $product->get_name() . ' Price: ' . $product->get_price();
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" class="button">Richiedi Informazioni</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
global $product;
$product->get_name();
$product->get_price_html();
```

Don't forget to use `esc_attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','content_after_addtocart_button', 10, 2 );

function content_after_addtocart_button($product = null) { 
global $product;
echo '<div class="content-section">
<a href="mailto:riccardoairone@gmail.com?&subject= Richiesta Informazioni&body= $product->get_name() ??? $product->get_price() ??? ">
<input type="button" value="Richiedi Informazioni"/ ></a></div>'; 
}
```